# Code samples for statistical algorithms in Map Reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, statistics

What are some code examples of using statistical algorithms (linear/logistic regression ) using MapReduce on a HDFS?
Basically, so far I have only found simple examples like word counting, I am looking for some more real world statistical algorithms in MR

Comment: Which language? Which library?

Comment: I added the tags, looking to implement learning algorithms in Apache Map Reduce

Comment: First, have a look on Apache Spark.
Second, check Apache Mahout.